# Macro to copy from above cell range (a1 to d1) and paste into below 14 cells range (a14 to d14)

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to copy from above cell range (a1 to d1) and paste the same to below 14 rows in same range i.e. (a1 to d1).

Thanks & regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort in trying to solve the problem, SO is for specific programming questions, not asking others to do work for you.

Comment: you can start from here [How to record and run a macro](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html)

Comment: Guys please let me know the solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, your destination cell range would in fact be A15:D15

A simple way to achieve this would be:

```
Range("A15:D15").Value = Range("A1:D1").Value
```

If you want to make it relative, you could use variables:

```
i = 1

Range("A" & i+14 &":D" & i+14).Value = Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Value
```

Hope this helps!